# How to completely reinstall python (WITHOUT yum) on AWS Linux

Tags: python, linux, amazon-web-services, rpm, yum

A series of unfortunate events (in dev, thank goodness) basically has ruined my python2.7 environment.  The executable in `/usr/bin` got clobbered and some rpms ran amok.  So I no longer have a viable `import yum` environment.  I actually spun up another EC2 instance and copied off the `python` exec in hopes that the lib paths would be the same but sadly I got this (running with `-v`):

```
( various imports then )
import gpg.core # precompiled from /usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/gpg/core.pyc
# /usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/gpg/gpgme.pyc matches 
/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/gpg/gpgme.py
import gpg.gpgme # precompiled from /usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/gpg/gpgme.pyc
dlopen("/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/gpg/_gpgme.so", 2);
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/gpg/__init__.py", line 101, in <module>
  from . import core
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/gpg/core.py", line 34, in <module>
  from . import gpgme
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/gpg/gpgme.py", line 17, in <module>
_gpgme = swig_import_helper()
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/gpg/gpgme.py", line 16, in swig_import_helper
return importlib.import_module('_gpgme')
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
__import__(name)
ImportError: No module named _gpgme
```

This is sort of disturbing because of course `_gpgme.so` is in the same dir as `gpgme.py` and `ldd` on `_gpgme.so` looks OK:

```
-bash-4.2$ ldd /usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/gpg/_gpgme.so
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffe2cf6d000)
libpython2.7.so.1.0 => /usr/lib64/libpython2.7.so.1.0 (0x00007ff166d5d000)
libgpgme.so.11 => /usr/lib64/libgpgme.so.11 (0x00007ff166b27000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007ff16690b000)
libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007ff166547000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007ff166343000)
libutil.so.1 => /lib64/libutil.so.1 (0x00007ff166140000)
libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007ff165e3e000)
libassuan.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libassuan.so.0 (0x00007ff165c2e000)
libgpg-error.so.0 => /lib64/libgpg-error.so.0 (0x00007ff165a2a000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007ff1673e7000)
```

So the question is:  how does one force remove python from an AWS Linux image (`Linux version 4.9.75-25.55.amzn1.x86_64 (mockbuild@gobi-build-64013) (gcc version 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-11) (GCC) ) #1 SMP Fri Jan 5 23:50:27 UTC 2018`) and reinstall it **WITHOUT the benefit of yum**, and then install the necessary yum bits such that `/usr/bin/yum` (which pretty much just `import yum`) works?

I know this question is a partial dupe but I have searched stackoverflow and everything seems to lead back to installing python with yum (which I can't) or installing modules with pip (which keeps going to installing pip with yum!) or very broadly saying `rpm --erase vagueness` followed by `rpm -i vagueness`.

I did manually rebuild a python exec from source and that runs, but of course it does not come with `yum` and I cannot seem to find anything in `pip search` (I got pip running again) that would produce the `yum` module I seek.  You'd think `pip install yum` would be right there but no.  Maybe I missed something...?

I have to believe that there is perhaps a slow but stable way to do this.  Knocking out the `/usr/bin/python2.7` exec shouldn't create a situation where I seem to have a chicken-and-egg problem...

Answer (score 3):

Before you follow these steps, download the python-package-version.rpm file to a local directory on the same machine. See step-0 below to get the exact version.

```
0. Get the python package name
$ rpm -q python

1. Remove python forcefully
$ rpm -e --nodeps <python-package-name>

2. Install the rpm from local dir.
$ rpm -ivvh python-some-version.rpm

3. Retry your yum command
$ yum install <some package>
```

If (3) fails, you can reinstall yum using rpm, same way that you reinstall `python`.

From OP's comment, it seems `python` was never installed on the system, otherwise the dependencies would have been on the system. If on step-2, it asks for dependencies, then one has to download them manually to the same local dir and then invoke.

```
$ rpm -ivh *.rpm
```

or do a dry-run first

```
$ rpm -ivh --test *.rpm
```

Comment: 0 and 1 went well.  :-)   Got this on 2:
error: Failed dependencies:
 python-libs(x86-64) = 2.7.13-3.fc25 is needed by python-2.7.13-3.fc25.x86_64
 python-pip is needed by python-2.7.13-3.fc25.x86_64
 python-setuptools is needed by python-2.7.13-3.fc25.x86_64

Do I have to manually bring those down?

Comment: I thought you had python installed, but somehow got corrupted. Your comment tells me python was never installed on the system, otherwise the dependencies would have already installed. In this case, yes, download the dependencies to the same local dir. See updated answer.

Comment: @iamuser : Just started on that journey.   Is it a matter of pulling each one (like python-libs) and running #2 to find additional dependencies?   No way to do transitive closure...  I guess that's why we have yum.

Comment: correct. rpm will not be able to resolve dependencies and `yum` does that for you. Unfortunately, there is no other way than downloading the dependencies one by one. Since you have a system that is up and running, I would assume this list not to be too long.

Comment: Correct.  A tad tedious, but suitable punishment for my carelessness earlier.   Thanks.