# Centos 7 - No module named yum - Accidentally removed Python site-packages

Tags: python, centos, centos7, yum

I accidentally removed my Python's site-packages which means I got no any modules. Unfortunately, I noticed too late that the Yum uses a module named `yum` which is installed in the Python's site-packages where is located in `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages`.
I was trying to reinstall yum but no `yum` module was installed.

Hope to find an answer,
thanks!

Comment: See if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48389406/how-to-completely-reinstall-python-without-yum-on-aws-linux

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this issue by installing CentOS on a VM and then `scp` the python2.7 directory to the server.

Answer (score 0):

Try rpm -V yum which checks for issues with yum

Comment: I got a lot of missing site-packages